# MySql POWER() large exponent - DOUBLE value is out of range

Tags: mysql

I have an issue to transfer a python calculation formula into MySQL view, Mysql Power function returns every time DOUBLE value is out of range for POWER.

Python formula

```
exponent = (3 - 1) * 100000
my_value = 0.9654 - 0.9650
result = my_value / 10 ** exponent
```

Transferred into MySQL but because the exponent is big is resulting every time in DOUBLE value is out of range for POWER

```
SELECT 0.9604 / POWER(10, (4 - 3) * 100000);
result in DOUBLE value is out of range for POWER
```

Will appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh?  `DOUBLE` is limited to about 10 ** 308.  You are asking for 10 ** 200000.  It *should* overflow.

(The `SELECT` is asking for only 10**100000, but that is still too big.)

Virtually all floating point "DOUBLE" implementations in computers (at least since the late '80s) have the same limitations.  More discussion:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding

Comment: thanks for the answer, also did a research about it, will reward the bountry to your answer as is totally correct in 5h will be able to award it